# How deploy these on my raspberry pi running Apache?

Tags: html, apache, web, raspberry-pi

I transfer a pdf file to HTML online and I got a file downloaded, which contains four files: `xxxxx.htm`, `image.jpg`, `xxxxx.pdf`, and a folder called `xxxxx_images` which contains a picture called `xxxxx1*1.jpg`.

If I only put the HTML into the raspberry, the PDF picture doesn't show up. So where should I put the image in? The website is store in `/var/www/index.html`.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>    
    <HEAD>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
        <TITLE>Created by BCL easyConverter SDK 3 (HTML Version)</TITLE>
        <STYLE type="text/css">
            body {
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-left: 0px;
            }
            #page_1 {
                position:relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 130px 0px 793px 80px;
                padding: 0px;
                border: none;
                width: 714px;
            }
            #page_1 #dimg1 {
                position:absolute;
                top:8px;
                left:0px;
                z-index:-1;
                width:47px;
                height:14px;
                font-size: 1px;
                line-height:nHeight;
            }
            #page_1 #dimg1 #img1 {
                width:47px;
                height:14px;
            }
            .ft0 {
                font: 19px'Arial';
                color: #606060;
                line-height: 22px;
            }
            .ft1 {
                font: 11px'Arial';
                line-height: 14px;
            }
            .ft2 {
                font: 13px'Arial';
                line-height: 16px;
            }
            .p0 {
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 67px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
            .p1 {
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 67px;
                margin-top: 25px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
            .p2 {
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 67px;
                margin-top: 59px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
            .p3 {
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 67px;
                margin-top: 42px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
        </STYLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <DIV id="page_1">
            <DIV id="dimg1">
                <IMG src="Hello%20World_images/Hello%20World1x1.jpg" id="img1">
            </DIV>
            <P class="p0 ft0">Hello world</P>
            <P class="p1 ft1">
                <NOBR>123-456-7890</NOBR>no_reply@example.com</P>
            <P class="p2 ft0">Hello world</P>
            <P class="p3 ft2">This is a pdf ﬁle for test.</P>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: @Huey I use a online pdf2html tool, and the code like this:

Comment: @Huey 
</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<DIV id="page_1">
<DIV id="dimg1">
<IMG src="Hello%20World_images/Hello%20World1x1.jpg" id="img1">
</DIV>


<P class="p0 ft0">Hello world</P>
<P class="p1 ft1"><NOBR>123-456-7890</NOBR> no_reply@example.com</P>
<P class="p2 ft0">Hello world</P>
<P class="p3 ft2">This is a pdf ﬁle for test.</P>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: @Huey already put it, please help me thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image path is probably incorrect. Your HTML code specifies an `img` with a relative path: `Hello%20World_images/Hello%20World1x1.jpg`, but your question states you have:

> a file called xxxxx_images which contains a picture called xxxxx1*1.jpg.

I'm not sure what that means, but do make sure your image is in the location specified by your HTML, or edit the `src` attribute of your `img` tag to match the actual file location.